# PHP How to add entire array into MongoDB document field

Tags: php, arrays, mongodb

I'm using a `php` page to insert new documents in my MongoDB database. I want to add an array of authors into a document field (`authors:['Sally Sue', 'Billy Bob']`) through a URI.

Here's my php page contents:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php'; // Composer autoloader

use MongoDB\Driver\Manager as Mongo;

// Set $_GET variables
if (isset($_GET['authors'])){
    $authors = explode(',', filter_var($_GET['authors'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING));
} else {
    $authors = 'N/A';
}

$mongo = new Mongo("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/myDB");
$db = new MongoDB\Database($mongo, "myDB");    
$collection = $db->selectCollection("articles");
$result = $collection->insertOne([
    'authors' => $authors,
]);

print_r($result);

?>
```

**URI string**:

```
http://x.x.x.x/mySite/insertArticle.php?authors=Sally%20Sue,%20Billy%20Bob
```

However, the code is inserting my `$authors` variable as a string:

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in /var/www/html/mySite/insertArticle.php on line 17
```

How can I insert the `$authors` variable as an array? Do I have to use a `for` loop or is there a way to insert the entire array contents all at once as one variable?

Comment: Which is line number 61?

Comment: Oops, that should say line `16`. It's the line `'authors' => $authors`.

Comment: Maybe you want `collection.insertMany()` - do you want all authors in 1 document or couple?

Comment: You can try like ‘authors’ => [$authors]

Comment: Multiple authors for 1 document

Comment: @RahulMeshram - Thanks so much! For some reason I could not find anyone on Google saying how to do this. They kept saying you had to specify a particular index whenever referencing an array. Worked great.

Comment: @velkoon Your welcome. I posted my answer with confirmations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either way to work this code as follows

```
 ‘authors’ => [$authors]
```

Comment: Please add link to formal mongoDB doc - this will help future programmers

Comment: I wish mate. I am on my cell it’s difficult to ctrl + L or something. I hope you understand. Tomorrow I will do for sure